# Eliminar elemento lista y renderizaar nueva lista Flask Python

Tags: python, lista, arraylist, flask

estoy teniendo un problema queriendo eliminar un elemento de la lista guardado en una variable local como muestroa continuacion.

-Hasta aca todo normal, ya que se agregan los elementos a la lista.

```
@main.route("/insert_part", methods=["GET", "POST"])
 def insert_part():
if request.method == 'POST':
    msj = request.form['parte']
    # Data to be written
    _parte = {
        "id": msj,
        "fecha": 56,
        "usuario": msj,
        "longitud": 56,
        "peso": msj,
        "descripcion": 56,
    }

    lista.append(_parte)
    print(type(lista))

    return render_template('order/new_order.html', lista=lista)
```

-Si elimino un elemento, muestra el popup conel id a eliminar y lo saca de la lista.

```
@main.route("/delete_list/<string:id>", methods=["POST"]) 
 def delete_list(id):
 data=[]
 lis=lista

 for x in lis:
    if not x["id"] in [id]:
        data.append(x)
 # print(data)

 return redirect(url_for("order_blueprint.insert_part", list=data))
```

Ahora ya no se ve ningun elemento el la lista pero si agrego otro item se muestra toda la lista completa sin el elemento eliminado.

Gracias de antemano.

No puedo renderizar la nueva lista sin el elemento eliminado.